# Link the same text to different targets in reStructuredText

Tags: markdown, restructuredtext

How can I make two links have the same text but different targets in reStructuredText? The following script doesn't work but can help you get the point:

```
This Python_ is not the same as that Python_.

.. _Python2: https://docs.python.org/2/
.. _Python3: https://docs.python.org/3/
```

This job can be done in Markdown:

```
This [Python][Python2] is not the same as that [Python][Python3].

[Python2]: https://docs.python.org/2/
[Python3]: https://docs.python.org/3/
```

Result:

This [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/) is not the same as that [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution:

```
This `Python <Python2_>`_ is not the same as that `Python <Python3_>`_.

.. _Python2: https://docs.python.org/2/
.. _Python3: https://docs.python.org/3/
```

---

Found a solution with directives and subsitutions. Not sure if this is the best.

```
This |Python2|_ is not the same as that |Python3|_.

.. |Python2| replace:: Python
.. |Python3| replace:: Python
.. _Python2: https://docs.python.org/2/
.. _Python3: https://docs.python.org/3/
```